# Spring Authorisation server returning 404 for token endpoint after authenticating user

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I am creating an authorization server with a password grant.
Below is the configuration:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AuthorisationServerConfig {

    private final RSAProperties rsaProperties;
    AuthorisationServerConfig(final RSAProperties rsaProperties){
        this.rsaProperties=rsaProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.PASSWORD)
                .scope("read")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        //@formatter:off
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(ar->ar.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic();
        //@formatter:on
        return httpSecurity.build();
    }



    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings providerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .issuer("http://localhost:9090")
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        RSAKey rsaKey = new RSAKey.Builder(rsaProperties.publicKey()).privateKey(rsaProperties.privateKey()).build();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService users() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}
```

I have enabled the debug logs and can see that the user is getting authenticated but i receive 404 for the token endpoint.

```
oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=password&scope=read
```

Below are the logs:

```
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=password&scope=read
o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=admin, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, credentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=password&scope=read
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=password&scope=read
o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error?grant_type=password&username=admin&password=password&scope=read
```

Below are the dependencies details:

```
plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.1"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:1.0.0")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to import default auth server configuration using `@Import(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class)` or add in the security filter chain using.

```
OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
http
    .getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
    .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
```

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be several issues going on here.

1. You are using the wrong endpoint. `/oauth2/token` is the [default URI](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-model.html#configuring-authorization-server-settings).
2. The `password` grant type [is not supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#feature-list) because [it has been removed](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-18#section-2.4) from version 2.1 of the spec.
3. Related, client authentication for the `/oauth2/token` endpoint is configured via the `RegisteredClientRepository` (via `clientId()` and `clientSecret()`), not the `UserDetailsService`.

   The `UserDetailsService` is used for configuring the Spring Security authentication for end-users, which would be used for the `authorization_code` grant only. Therefore, `admin:password` is not valid credentials for client authentication, only for user authentication.

Comment: Even after updating the default URI  the issue persisted. I had to update the code with new configuration model.
OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http); 
or import it using 
@Import(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.class) and the issue was resolved